# How to add dates in java without any libraries

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a Date-Object that consists of (day,month,year) and I need to write methods to add days, months or entire dates to a first date without using any libraries. I kind of figured it has to do with converting a date to all days since a certain point and converting back but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it even mean to add two dates together?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is clearly homework which we are not going to do for you.

Comment: like: (01-01-1000)+(01-01-1000) = (02-02-2000)

Comment: It is indeed homework. I am not expecting you to do it for me but I just cannot get my head around it. Maybe if you have an idea you might try and explain it to me so I can do it myself?

Comment: Presumably you have some base code with the date object? You'll need to convert your date into some summable unit like days as you said. Not sure how else to guide you without doing it for you.

Comment: Yes I have a way of converting a date into summable days but I cannot figure out how to convert it back into a date

Comment: A good place to start (regarding questions on SO in general, not dates) is to read [How to ask questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: @kden9798 Post further info (such as being homework) as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. Also, your example of adding two dates makes no sense, has no meaning. Think through your problem (the business rules) thoroughly before you start programming.

Answer (score 0):

If your are working with Java 7, it is easier to code with Calendar.
It comes with the JDK.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: The TC clearly stated that he is required *not* to use libraries. And Calendar has been around since almost the dawn of time, aka Java 1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Date {
private int day;
private int month;
public int year;

private int [] noOfDays = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        
public int getDay() {
    return day;
}
public void setDate(int tmpDay, int tmpMonth, int tmpYear) 
{
    if(tmpYear > 2200 || tmpYear < 1900)
        year = 2021;
    else
        year = tmpYear;
    if(tmpMonth > 12 || tmpMonth < 1)
        month = 1;
    else month = tmpMonth;
    
    if(isLeapYear(tmpYear))
        noOfDays[2]=29;
    else
        noOfDays[2]=28;
    
    if(tmpDay > noOfDays[month] || tmpDay < 1)
        day=1;
    else
        day = tmpDay;
}

public boolean isLeapYear(int tmpYear)
{
    return true;
}
public void addDays(int noOfDaysToAdd)
{
    for(int iTemp=0; iTemp < noOfDaysToAdd; iTemp++)
    {
        day++;
        if(day > noOfDays[month])
        {
            day = 1;
            month++;
            if(month > 12)
            {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this to addDays in a Date, I believe you can write a method to addMonths, addYears & a main class without any help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).